# How do you Mock AutoMapper MapTo?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, moq

I've seen lots of questions around unit testing automapper 'map' but how do you mock 'MapTo'. This expects an IMapper as it's object. So, this is what I have so far:

```
private Mock<IMapper> _mapper;

[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
    _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

    //other stuff initialised.
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    _mapper.Setup(m => m.MapTo<IList<Something>>(_mapper.Object)).Returns(myList);

    //setup repository etc.
}
```

This throws an error of "Invalid setup on an extension method...". So, how do I mock out the call to 'MapTo'?

Just to clarify, I know I can use an actual version of the mapper and create actual maps like:

```
private MapperConfiguration CreateMaps()
{
    return new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
   {
       mc.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyObject>();
       mc.CreateMap<MyOtherEntity, MyOtherObject>();
   });
}

_mapper = new Mapper(CreateMaps());
```

However, I was still curious how to mock it. It seems an easy thing to do with Map but not MapTo

Comment: Why mock IMapper? You can simply use it in your tests.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - Yep, I know, just curious. See update

Comment: You'll need to wrap automapper with your own IMapper abstraction - where only your concrete MyAutoMapper concrete class implenenting the wrapper interface is allowed to access AMs static and extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can.  `MapTo(...)` is a basically a static method like any other with some fancy syntax that makes it look like part of the object in your IDE.

Given it's not actually part of the object you're mocking, your options are limited.  Your best bet is to look at the code for `MapTo(...);` maybe the internals are mockable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't? It's not worth it. Treat it like JSON.NET.